# PyOpenCL: What is Event.wait() for?

Tags: wait, pyopencl

This function is uncommented in the PyOpenCL documentation: http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/runtime.html?highlight=enqueue#pyopencl.Event.wait

My problem is: I have to call a kernel in a for-loop and after each call enqueue a copy operation with `pyopencl.enqueue_copy_buffer(dest, src, size)`. First I did this with `.wait()` appended (i.e. `pyopencl.enqueue_copy_buffer(dest, src, size).wait()`) because I found this in an example. Then I removed `.wait()` and got a very significant speedup.

So what is this function for and under which conditions can it be abandoned? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`.wait()` will wait for the operation to be completed. If your code can proceed without it being finished (or even started), you can leave it out. Note that this is not related to the order of operations in the queue: they will be executed (unless you use out-of-order queue) in the order you enqueued them, one after another.

Comment: Aha, so in the case of a loop where I call a kernel and enqueue a buffer copy right after that, I can leave wait() out because the kernel call and the copy function call are enqueued in the proper sequence, right?

Comment: Yes, just make sure you don't modify your data before the queue is synchronized (in that case, depending on exact timing in each individual case, data might be copied to the device before or after being modified, or in the middle). Enqueing data and kernel right after that is ok.